# Using sets in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to use sets in standard SQL. Is it possible somehow describe column type like selection from set of something `(Example Color=[Red, Green, Blue] )`. Should I describe this like datatype or use special tables that describes sets? I need this feature to be as much as possible standard in most SQL servers. What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Create a check constraint or use a proper lookup table as recommended by JB Nizet

Answer (score 1):

Some databases have enumerated types, but not all. If you really want something portable, then create a table `color` containing a single column (`name`) and three rows (red, green and blue). And in the tables that have a column that should hold a color, define a foreign key constraint that references `color.name`.